# Reflection de um Objeto que é propriedade de outro

Tags: c#, genéricos, reflexão

No meu código utilizo uma classe chamada `GenericField<T>` que é utilizada em todos os atributos de outra classe chamada `Aplicacao`. Até tudo bem, porém, em outra parte do código necessito obter via *reflection* o nome de um atributo específico da classe `Aplicacao`, que na verdade é uma instância de `GenericField<int>`.

Eu tentei o código abaixo mas não obtive a resposta esperada (o nome atributo que seria "id", ao invés, obtive "GerericField1"), a implementação das duas classes está logo em seguida.

```
Aplicacao obj = new Aplicacao();
MessageBox.Show(obj.id.GetType().Name.ToString());
```

## Classe `GenericField`

```
[Serializable]
public class GenericField<T>
{
    private bool changeOldValue = true;

    private T _Value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            if (changeOldValue)
                _OldValue = value;

            _Value = value;
            changeOldValue = false;
        }
    }

    private T _OldValue;
    public T OldValue
    {
        get { return _OldValue; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_Value == null)
            return "";
        return _Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

## Classe `Aplicacao`

```
public class Aplicacao : Objeto_DTL
{
    public Aplicacao()
    {
        _id = new GenericField<int>();
        _nome = new GenericField<string>();
        _descricao = new GenericField<string>();
        _criacao = new GenericField<DateTime>();
    }

    public override string ToString() { return _id.ToString() + " - " + _nome.ToString(); }

    private GenericField<int> _id;
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public GenericField<int> id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private GenericField<string> _nome;
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public GenericField<string> nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
        set { _nome = value; }
    }

    private GenericField<string> _descricao;
    [DisplayName("Descrição")]
    public GenericField<string> descricao
    {
        get { return _descricao; }
        set { _descricao = value; }
    }

    private GenericField<DateTime> _criacao;
    [DisplayName("Criação")]
    public GenericField<DateTime> criacao
    {
        get { return _criacao; }
        set { _criacao = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aqui: `MessageBox.Show(obj.id.GetType().Name.ToString());` você recupera o nome do tipo da propriedade id de obj. Essa propriedade tem tipo GenericField.

Comment: E como recupero o nome?

Comment: Você quer o nome da propriedade? Não faz muito sentido. Se você sabe qual é a propriedade, você sabe o nome dela.

Comment: Pretendo criar uma função que irá ter como parâmetro um GenericField e dentro dela precisarei saber o nome do atributo passado como parametro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver utilizando o C# 6, utilize a palavra reservada **nameof**

Como exemplo sugiro que siga o link abaixo 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/the-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0-nameof-operator/

O operador **nameof** veio junto do C# 6 para facilitar a exibição literal de um nome da propriedade.

Exemplo:
**nameof**(objeto.Propriedade)

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor sua resposta?

Comment: Claro que sim, dê uma olhada neste link e veja se te atende.

 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/the-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0-nameof-operator/

Comment: É exatamente isso, gostaria de uma edição na sua resposta colocando os principais pontos do link, links são bem vindos, mas insira na resposta os pontos chaves para responder a dúvida em questão.

Comment: Ela resolveria meu problema mas infelizmente ainda utilizo o Visual Studio   2013 e pelo que vi ele não suporta  a palavra reservada nameof.

Answer (score 2):

Agora entendo o que está precisando. Acho que, da forma como implementa as classes, não é possível.

Veja só: a propriedade (que você quer recuperar o nome) é do tipo `GenericField`. Quando um método recebe esse valor, tudo que sabe é acerca da variável (do tipo `GenericField`). Não tem como saber onde ela está referenciada (como propriedade da classe `Aplicacao`, e talvez outro lugar).

No seu caso isso se reflete na sua chamada obj.id.[etc.]. Você usa o nome da propriedade. Claro que, imagino, o seu código final não vai ser assim (a propriedade vai ser passada adiante, e não vai ser chamada pelo próprio `obj.{propriedade}`).

Um exemplo do que você está querendo: você tem uma classe `A` com um membro chamado `id` e um chamado `quantidade`, ambos int. Você passa os dois para um método (digamos `calcular(int a, int b)`, e quer descobrir, dentro do método, o nome desses membros dentro da classe `A`. Não é possível.

A solução aqui seria incluir dentro de `GenericField` um campo `string propertyName`, e talvez um campo `object Parent`.

Comment: Realmente eu já tinha pensado em uma solução como o campo `string propertyName` mas estava procurando algo mais prático.
Erei baixar o demo do VS 2015 e testar o nameof depois decido qual usar pois ainda estamos na fase de projeto e prototipagem. Assim que tiver uma definição posto aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
O que você pode fazer também é pegar o atributo "DisplayName" da propriedade.

Ex :

Extension method:

```
public static T GetAttributeFrom<T>(this object instance, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
{
    var attrType = typeof(T);
    var property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (T)property .GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false).First();
}
```

Code:

```
Aplicacao app = new Aplicacao();
var name = app.GetAttributeFrom<DisplayAttribute>("descricao").Name;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code-programmatically

Comment: Já utilizo o "DisplayName" para exibir o nome formatado (com caracteres especiais) e eu teria o mesmo trabalho que criar uma propriedade a mais na classe `GenericField` e preenche-la realmente acho que vou esperar pelo VS 2015 já que tenho tempo para isso, mas en todo caso obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Por favor altere o código para:

**obj.GetType().GetProperty("id").Name**

--Edit

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Aplicacao obj = new Aplicacao();


        Console.WriteLine(GetName(() => obj.id));
    }

    public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
        return member.Member.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Pretendo criar uma função que irá ter como parâmetro um GenericField e dentro dela precisarei saber o nome do atributo passado como parâmetro por isso não posso usar da forma que descreveu pois não sei qual propriedade será passada.

Comment: Ao invés de incluir uma nova resposta, edite a que você já havia incluído. Pode fazer isto clicando em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/73344/edit), logo abaixo do conteúdo da resposta.

Comment: Já editei, testei e funciona!

Comment: Resolveu? Se sim poderia marcar como resposta?